# Where is there so much whitespace at the top on mobile safari

Tags: css, mobile, mobile-safari, viewport, responsive-interaction

This is extremely weird. I can barely replicate this, but I have an issue where a particular url on our site will load with a ton of while space at the top.

Here is the current viewport info:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This only happens on safari on iOS 8+. On an iPhone 6. Any clues? This is not easily replicable, but definitely happens at least 5-10% of the times. Basically the top of the page is completely white. The content starts at the bottom of the phone.

[image]

More information:

URL: http://www.mytime.com/deals/CA/Irvine/Health-&-Beauty/Hair-Coloring/Maxwell%27s-Salon-of-London/mt-YiI-0H0d1nXpuOBf7LW-ig?utm_source=localcom&utm_medium=affiliate&utm_campaign=Maxwell%27s+Salon+of+London&localservice=hair-coloring
Safari version:
iOS version: 8.2 (12D508)
Model: iPhone 6 (MG4W2LL/A)

Comment: A picture is helpful to see the symptom, but not the cause (code, please).

Comment: @Diodeus added more info in the edits - thanks for any help

Comment: So it doesn't happen most of the time, only some of the time, and you don't know the exact triggers? Hm, those are the hardest things to debug. Try to find out what the differences are. Are you zoomed in, some of the time? Is the page sometimes displayed inside a frame? Do you come from a link, with a fragment identifier (that is, a # in the URL)? Different POSTed data?